# How to construct an np.array with fromiter

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to construct an `np.array` by sampling from a python generator, that yields one row of the array per invocation of `next`.  Here is some sample code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.eye(9)
labels = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])

def extract_one_class(X,labels,y):
""" Take an array of data X, a column vector array of labels, and one particular label y.  Return an array of all instances in X that have label y """

    return X[np.nonzero(labels[:] == y)[0],:]

def generate_points(data, labels, size):
""" Generate and return 'size' pairs of points drawn from different classes """

     label_alphabet = np.unique(labels)
     assert(label_alphabet.size > 1)

     for useless in xrange(size):
         shuffle(label_alphabet)
         first_class = extract_one_class(data,labels,label_alphabet[0])
         second_class = extract_one_class(data,labels,label_alphabet[1])
         pair = np.hstack((first_class[randint(0,first_class.shape[0]),:],second_class[randint(0,second_class.shape[0]),:]))
         yield pair

points = np.fromiter(generate_points(data,labels,5),dtype = np.dtype('f8',(2*data.shape[1],1)))
```

The `extract_one_class` function returns a subset of data: all data points belonging to one class label.  I would like to have **points** be an `np.array` with `shape = (size,data.shape[1])`.  Currently the code snippet above returns an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The documentation of `fromiter` claims to return a one-dimensional array.  Yet others have used fromiter to construct record arrays in numpy before (e.g http://iam.al/post/21116450281/numpy-is-my-homeboy).

Am I off the mark in assuming I can generate an array in this fashion?  Or is my numpy just not quite right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify `generate_points` to yield single floats instead of np.arrays, use `np.fromiter` to form a 1D array, and then use `.reshape(size, -1)` to make it a 2D array.

```
points = np.fromiter(
    generate_points(data,labels,5)).reshape(size, -1)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to modify generate_points to yield single floats.  The idea is to sample from a data set where the units are N dimensional vectors of floats.  If I were to sample one dimension at a time, I'd have to still use a for loop in the calling code to see when a whole row had been sampled.  The goal for me is to express this as one statement iterating over what's returned from the generator.

Comment: An N-dimensional array can be "converted" into a 1D array by using the `ravel()` method. You can then re-convert it into an N-dimensional array using the `reshape()` method. So in `generate_points` you could `for val in pair.ravel(): yield val`, pump that into `np.fromiter`, and use `reshape(size, -1)` on the other side to obtain your desired 2D array. I would post explicit code to show you what I mean, but the code you posted doesn't actually run (it raises an IndexError: invalid index) and I'm not seeing how to easily fix it.

Comment: I've fixed the IndexError bug, and your ravel suggestion works well, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

As you've noticed, the documentation of [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) explains that the function creates a 1D array. You won't be able to create a 2D array that way, and @unutbu method of returning a 1D array that you reshape afterwards is a sure go.

However, you can indeed create structured arrays using `fromiter`, as illustrated by:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = itertools.izip((1,2,3),(10,20,30))
>>> r = np.fromiter(a,dtype=[('',int),('',int)])
array([(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

but look, `r.shape=(3,)`, that is, `r` is really nothing but 1D array of records, each record being composed of two integers. Because all the fields have the same `dtype`, we can take a view of `r` as a 2D array

```
>>> r.view((int,2))
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 2, 20],
       [ 3, 30]])
```

So, yes, you could try to use `np.fromiter` with a `dtype` like `[('',int)]*data.shape[1]`: you'll get a 1D array of length `size`, that you can then view this array as `((int, data.shape[1]))`. You can use floats instead of ints, the important part is that all fields have the same dtype.

If you *really* want it, you can use some fairly complex `dtype`. Consider for example

```
r = np.fromiter(((_,) for _ in a),dtype=[('',(int,2))])
```

Here, you get a 1D structured array with 1 field, the field consisting of an array of 2 integers. Note the use of `(_,)` to make sure that each record is passed as a tuple (else `np.fromiter` chokes). But do you need that complexity?

Note also that as you know the length of the array beforehand (it's `size`), you should use the `counter` optional argument of `np.fromiter` for more efficiency.

Comment: He has a secondary problem of returning a 2D array, but `np.frombuffer` needs single elements (possible 1D arrays when it gets packed into a recarray). So he must modify his iterator with an inner loop. It might be nicer to just construct a list and use `concatenate`.

Comment: @seberg You meant `fromiter`? But yes, in that case, it'd be easier to use `concatenate` on a list. As a side note, `recarray` is usually used only to refer to structured arrays that can access fields as attributes...

Answer (score 1):

Following some suggestions here, I came up with a fairly general drop-in replacement for `numpy.fromiter()` that satisfies the requirements of the OP:

```
import numpy as np
def fromiter(iterator, dtype, *shape):
    """Generalises `numpy.fromiter()` to multi-dimesional arrays.

    Instead of the number of elements, the parameter `shape` has to be given,
    which contains the shape of the output array. The first dimension may be
    `-1`, in which case it is inferred from the iterator.
    """
    res_shape = shape[1:]
    if not res_shape:  # Fallback to the "normal" fromiter in the 1-D case           
        return np.fromiter(iterator, dtype, shape[0])

    # This wrapping of the iterator is necessary because when used with the
    # field trick, np.fromiter does not enforce consistency of the shapes
    # returned with the '_' field and silently cuts additional elements.
    def shape_checker(iterator, res_shape):
        for value in iterator:
            if value.shape != res_shape:
                raise ValueError("shape of returned object %s does not match"
                                 " given shape %s" % (value.shape, res_shape))
            yield value,

    return np.fromiter(shape_checker(iterator, res_shape),
                       [("_", dtype, res_shape)], shape[0])["_"]
```